# Inserting a node to a BST

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, binary-search-tree

This is the first part of my insert function

```
void BinTree::insert(Node * temp, NodeData * insData)
{
    if (temp == NULL)
    {

        temp = new Node;
        temp->pData = insData;
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        return;
    }
       //recursively go left or right
       //....rest of the function
}
```

The problem lies in the first if statement. I'm adding several Nodes. 
Here's the function that calls the insert function.

```
void BinTree::insertMiddle(NodeData* arr[], int bottom, int top)
{


    if (bottom <= top)
    {
        int middle = (bottom + top) / 2;

        if (arr[middle] == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(root, arr[middle]);
            arr[middle] = NULL;

            insertMiddle(arr, bottom, middle - 1);
            insertMiddle(arr, middle + 1, top);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I found that after I insert all the nodes, the root is still NULL. In fact, the first if-statement in the insert function turns true every time. 
It shouldn't be null after the first insert. 
I don't think I'm deleting anything or setting the root to NULL anywhere.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Repeat this: **Function parameters are local variables. Assignment to a local variable has no effect on the outside world**.

Comment: I wasn't aware that a pointer is passed by value. I thought it's a new pointer, but it points to the same object the passed pointer was pointing to, so it wouldn't matter. I was wrong though. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot verify the correctness of your code, but I think I see the problem you're facing at the moment. `insert` takes a pointer `temp` to a node, changes it to some allocated `new` node. But the pointer `temp` is passed by value, so the assignment inside the function `insert`

```
temp = new Node;
```

will not be visible at the caller, because it changes a *copy* of the passed parameter. When you call it with

```
insert(root, arr[middle]);
```

the change of the parameter `temp` (passed by value) inside the function `insert` will not change the value of `root` in the caller.

If you want the function `insert` to change the parameter passed by the caller, change its prototype to pass the parameter *by reference*:

```
void BinTree::insert(Node*& temp, NodeData * insData)
                         ^^^
```

This way, temp is a parameter of type `pointer-to-Node` and is passed by reference. So any changes to the pointer will be visible in the caller code.